Time series - Linear filter model
I was going through the linear-filter-model in Time series.
"Linear Filter Model.  an observable time series  in which successive values are highly dependent can frequently be regarded as generated from a series of independent ‘‘shocks’’ . These shocks are random drawings from a fixed distribution, usually assumed normal and having mean zero and variance 2 . Such a sequence of independent random variables , −1, −2, … is called a white noise process. The white noise process  is supposed transformed to the process  by what is called a linear filter. The linear filtering operation simply takes a weighted sum of previous random shocks , so that  =  +  + 1−1 + 2−2 + ⋯ =  + () (1.2.1) In general,  is a parameter that determines the ‘‘level’’ of the process, and ()=1+ 1 + 22 + ⋯ is the linear operator that transforms  into  and is called the transfer function of the filter. The model representation can allow for a flexible range of patterns of dependence among values of the process {} expressed in terms of the independent (unobservable) random shocks . The sequence 1, 2, … formed by the weights may, theoretically, be finite or infinite. If this sequence is finite, or infinite and absolutely summable in the sense that ∑∞ =0 || < ∞, the filter is said to be stable and the process  is stationary. The parameter  is then the mean about which the process varies. Otherwise,  is nonstationary and  has no specific meaning except as a reference point for the level of the process."
Based on the details shared, I am not sure if this is the same as Moving-average model. Even MA model of order p is based on the linear combinations of the white-noise coefficients.
What exactly is the difference between MA model and linear-filter model. Please advise.
*Source:

TIME SERIES ANALYSIS Forecasting and Control

Fifth Edition: GEORGE E. P. BOX, GWILYM M. JENKINS, GREGORY C. REINSEL
GRETA M. LJUNG. (Chapter 1; page 7: Linear Filter Models)

Can you please edit to include a source for the citation?

@eashwar : if an AR(p) is stationary and causal, then it can always be represented by an infinite MA ( the linear combination of past errors ). This is probably why they are only considering the MA  in the linear filter discussion.

Thanks @mlofton. So linear filters are stationary AR processes, which are invertible MAs (infinite order).

Hi eashwar: I don't want to lead you in the wrong direction because I was just talking about time-series in the box-jenkins framework. The term "linear filter" also comes up in DSP where, if you have the impulse response of $x_t$, namely $h(t)$, then you can calculate $y_t = h(t) * x(t) $ to get the response. So, the term "linear filter" is kind of ambiguous depending on the field, time-series or dsp. But, even in ts, the filter doesn't have to be AR. One could have a time-series regression where $y_t = \beta_1 x_{t} + \beta_2 x_{t-2}$. This is not an AR model but it's still a linear filter.

So, I'm not sure if I'm answering your question but, in the Box-Jenkins framework, linear filters can be AR's or MA's or ARMA's but any causal, stationary pure AR model can be converted to an infinite MA. I hope this is clearer now ?

The equation in the comment starting: "I don't want to lead you" should read $y_t = \beta_1 x_{t-1} +  \beta_2  x_{t-2}$.

Thanks @mlofton. I get it now. Linear filters are interchangeable and can be MA, AR or ARMA. So, from that principle, the operation depicted in terms of the math expression makes sense. Thanks for clarifying the point.

Hi eashwar: Yes, all the box-jenkins models (ARIMA class ) can be thought of as linear filters. But the term "linear filter" is somewhat confusing because the DSP field also uses the term and it has similar meaning over there but not exactly the same. If that's a concern, I would check out an intro to DSP or a signals and systems type text. They will  give you the EE viewpoint of linear filter. It's a little different and more general than BJ but, if you're just interested in BJ, that's fine.
